# Opening .py files with micropython on TI Nspire

Tags: micropython, ti-nspire

I uploaded [Fabian Vogt's micropython](https://github.com/Vogtinator/micropython) port to my TI Nspire CX CAS, together with a couple of *.py.tns files to try. I can't find a way to load/launch those files.

As micropython does not include the os module, I can't use os.chdir to change the current directory and load the *.py files from the python shell. I tried from python shell:  open("documents/mydirectory/myfile")
with different extensions .py or .py.tns, without success.

I don't think the Nspire has anything like the terminal commmand line either.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways that you could do this, one easy way and one tedious way.

## 1. Map `.py` to `micropython` in your ndless.cfg

(`ndless.cfg` should be at `/documents/ndless/ndless.cfg`)

Like so:

```
ext.xxx=program-name
ext.xxx=program-name
ext.txt=nTxt
ext.py=micropython
ext.xxx=program-name
ext.xxx=program-name
```

You can edit this file either by copying it back and forth from your computer using TiLP or the official software, or you can edit it on-calc using [nTxt](https://www.omnimaga.org/ti-nspire-projects/ntxt-nspire-text-editor). (This requires a bit of fiddling with making a copy of `ndless.cfg` so that the mappings still exist to open the copied file `ndless.txt`).

Ndless should come with a standard `ndless.cfg` containing basic bindings for nTxt and a few popular emulators. If you don't have one, get the standard one [here](https://github.com/ndless-nspire/Ndless/blob/master/ndless/calcbin/ndless.cfg.tns). It will scan all directories (at least `/documents/*`, AFAIK) for programs. I've found that removing lines related to programs not on your Nspire will decrease load time.

---

## 2. Proper way to run a file in Python

To run a file in Python, you should do something like this:

```
with open("/documents/helloworld.py.tns","r") as file:
    exec(file.read())
```

This will properly close the file after executing, which I've noticed is quite important on the Nspire, as leaving files open has given me trouble before. Of course, if you'd like, you can do `exec(open("...","r").read())` and then handle closing the file yourself, but be warned: bad things can happen if you forget.

Also, you must remember to add the leading `/` and the `.tns` extension, or else strange things will happen, especially with writing to files.

---

That's about it! Feel free to ask more questions if needed, I'll be watching the `ti-nspire` tag.

(Just realized this question is quite old, but I guess it still might be helpful for others who end up on empty questions months later while trying to figure something out :P)